# Can't run Python programs from the terminal window, how do I fix this? (Windows 10, Python version 3.8.5)

Tags: python, windows, terminal

I've been studying Python for a month now and normally I run all my programs in Sublime Text 3.

Today I learn to run Python programs in the terminal window as introduced in [this section](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/appendixb/) of the Automate the Boring Stuff with Python [book](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/) following [this video](https://youtu.be/qHcHUHF_Qfo). Basically, I followed the instruction in the video and created the **hello.py** file as below:

```
#! python3
print('Hello, World!')
```

Then I opened the Command Prompt to run the file with the command: `py.exe c:\users\danh\mypythonscripts\hello.py`,
an error pops-up and states that ["This app can't run on your PC"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N1dL.png) and a line says that [Access is denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfGzd.png). I spent the whole day trying to fix this problem but still I couldn't get it running.

One thing is when I change the directory of the Command Prompt to run the file to **C:Windows\system32** (or run the Command Prompt as Administrator) and then run the command `py.exe c:\users\danh\mypythonscripts\hello.py`, it runs the file without any problem as [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc6LG.png).

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

---

Comment: Can you try running `where py.exe` in each place?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I run `where py.exe` in both places, [this is what I get](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/711943578410156115/746391036938551326/unknown.png)

Comment: @DanhTran Sounds like you haven't installed Python.

Comment: @Carcigenicate excuse my poor English if I don't fully understand your comment. I think I have a [64-bit version of Windows](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/711943578410156115/746391899346305034/unknown.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

When I looked into my user directory at `C:\Users\<Username>`, it appears that there is a [`py.exe`](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/711943578410156115/746710744019763340/EgBiYmrU8AAVJC8.png) file that has 0 bytes.

I was told [in this thread](https://twitter.com/zooba/status/1297122367173464065) that the `py.exe` file shouldn't be in my user directory so I removed that file and it fixed the problem.

I still don't know how the `py.exe` file got into my user directory and why it has 0 bytes so I'm not sure this solution could help others. For now, I will accept my own answer because it solves the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use Microsoft's new Windows 10 Metro-based auto-installing version of Python. It's included by default but, as you've found, it doesn't work very well.

Try installing [the version from the Python website](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

If you've got a 32-bit copy of Windows, make sure to install the 32-bit version; Windows isn't very good at running 64-bit programs from a 32-bit kernel. You can check by looking in your C: drive; if you haven't got a *Program Files (x86)* folder, install the 32-bit version.

Comment: I tried downloading the newest version of Python on the website and update it to 3.8.5 just a few hours ago.

Comment: @DanhTran Hmm… That's odd. Does it work when you remove the space in the shebang (first line)? (Also, I'm probably going to delete this answer soon, since it's wrong.)

Comment: I removed the space, but it still has the same problem, running in `c:\Windows\system32` but the error pop-up when I run it in `c:\User\Danh`. [image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/711943578410156115/746398730684465163/unknown.png)

Comment: Forgot to mention, I have the [Program Files (x86) folder](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/711943578410156115/746396249414041727/unknown.png), so I think I have a 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: @DanhTran I feel as though it's trying to load some DLLs… What happens when you miss out the `py.exe` in the invocation? (`.py` should be in that environment variable full of executable extensions.)

Comment: thank you so much for trying to help me with this problem. I was a bit tired last night so I went to get some sleep. This morning I went on with [the video](https://youtu.be/qHcHUHF_Qfo) to create the `.bat` file and set up the path system variable and then somehow I got things working as intended.

So basically instead of using `py.exe` in the command prompt and the `@py` in the `.bat` file, I use the `C:\Windows\py.exe` that I got from running `where py.exe`.
Not sure if that the right way to fix this problem, but I think I will write an answer for my question.

Comment: @DanhTran That shouldn't help in the slightest, but -.(o.o).- It's Windows, what can you do? (Have you tried running the Python program directly, as if it's a .exe file?)

Comment: A nice guy (Steve Dower, @zooba on Twitter) trying to help me with the problem, and as I took a look into my user directory, it appears in there that there is a [`py.exe`](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/711943578410156115/746710744019763340/EgBiYmrU8AAVJC8.png) file that has 0 bytes. I deleted it, and it fixed the problem! Still don't know why or how that `py.exe` got in my user directory, though. Cause Steve said that it definitely shouldn't be in there.

Comment: @DanhTran That's _weird_. Could you write up an answer?

Comment: as I mention in the comment I made above, I fixed the problem by deleting the `py.exe` file that has 0 bytes in my user directory. But I still don't know why or how it got in here so I'm not sure I could write a thoughtful answer to my question.
Edit: why Stacoverflow doesn't allow me to mention @wizzwizz4 - https://stackoverflow.com/users/5223757/wizzwizz4 in my comment?

Comment: @DanhTran I know you don't know how it got there, but posting (and accepting) an answer means it'll stop being an unanswered question – meaning it'll come up in search results better, and people won't keep coming here to try to answer it for the next few years.

Answer (score 0):

`python.exe` inside my `env\Scripts\` became 0kb for some reason. So I created another virtual-env and copied `python.exe` from there to this folder. then it started working.